# What's the most reliable port for adding an external monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink, usb-c

I'm doing purchasing research to buy a new laptop.

I want to connect two external monitors.

Every laptop I've seen contains one HDMI port, so that's one covered.

*Some* devices also have VGA, but they naturally tend to be a little bit outdated.

Which of the following is most reliable on Ubuntu, with adapters, for adding an additional external display?

- USB-C (I've read that there are problems)
- USB 3.0
- DisplayLink

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Define "most reliable" please.

Comment: The one mostly likely to work "out of the box", through a commonly available adapter.